# How to check the report of class layout in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio has a tool to check class layouts by using these commands:

```
$ cl /d1 reportSingleClassLayout<className> dir
$ cl /d1 reportAllClassLayout<className> dir
```

I wonder if VS Code has the same/similar tool?

Comment: `cl.exe` is the Visual C++ compiler. You can use it anywhere you can execute a command.

Comment: @molbdnilo: `c1` is not the same as `cl`.

Comment: I am surprised, as Visual Studio 2019 has `c1.dll` and `c1xx.dll` which are the *frontend* compilers for C and C++ respectively. The `c2.dll` is the optimizing backend compiler. But there is no `c1.exe` that can be called directly.

Comment: @TonyK No, but `c1.exe` does not exist, and those are known (albeit undocumented) options for `cl.exe`, so I think it's safe to assume a typo in the question.

Comment: Sorry it's a typo. Should be `cl`. I edited the question.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see. But I got an error on my mac terminal: `zsh: command not found: cl`. Is this due to macOS rather than windows?

Comment: It's because `cl.exe` is the Visual C++ compiler, and Visual C++ only exists for Windows. There might be similar functions in the tool chains you have installed on your mac.